# Select Join two different results same table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to get the user name and id two times from table users?

I need: ID user 3, ID user 4, NAME user 3 and NAME user 4

```
function getOrdem($id){
return $this->db
->select('*')
->from('ordens')
->join('users', 'users.id = ordens.idCriadorOs', 'inner')
->join('users', 'users.id = ordens.idFuncionarioOs', 'inner')
->join('cargos', 'cargos.idCargo = ordens.idFuncionarioOs', 'inner')
->join('empresas', 'empresas.idEmpresa = ordens.idClienteOs', 'inner')
->get_where('', array('idOs' => $id))
->row_array();
}
```

produces in array:

```
[idOs] => 2
[idClienteOs] => 3
[idFuncionarioOs] => 4
[idCriadorOs] => 5
[id] => 4
[first_name] => Anderson
[last_name] => Araújo
[idCargoUser] => 4
[idCargo] => 4
[nomeCargo] => Atendimento
[idEmpresa] => 3
[nomeEmpresa] => DJ Araujo
```

i need:

```
{
[idOs] => 2
[idClienteOs] => 3
[idFuncionarioOs] => 4
[idCriadorOs] => 5
[id] => 4
[first_name] => Anderson
[last_name] => Araújo
[id] => 5
[first_name] => Vitor
[last_name] => Hugo
[idCargoUser] => 4
[idCargo] => 4
[nomeCargo] => Atendimento
[idCargo] => 5
[nomeCargo] => WebDesigner
[idEmpresa] => 3
[nomeEmpresa] => DJ Araujo
)
```

i need:

```
idFuncionario = Anderson Araújo
```

and
    idCriadorOs = Vitor Hugo

Answer (score 0):

```
function getOrdem($id){
     return $this->db->select('*')

          ->join('users', 'users.id = ordens.idCriadorOs AND users.id = ordens.idFuncionarioOs', 'inner')
          ->join('cargos', 'cargos.idCargo = ordens.idFuncionarioOs', 'inner')
          ->join('empresas', 'empresas.idEmpresa = ordens.idClienteOs', 'inner')
          ->get_where('ordens', array('idOs' => $id))
          ->row_array();
```

}

Comment: Hi.. don't work..

I need with "idFuncionarioOs" get first_name "Anderson", last_name "Araujo" and with idCriadorOs get first_name "Vitor", last_name "Hugo"... both from "users" db

Comment: sorry, copy and try again, try to use AND instead OR